# How to lock visibility of scene panel elements?

Tags: 3d-view, scene, visibility

When switching between *Layout*, *Modeling* or *Shading* panels, the scene panel elements like *Select* and *Disable in Viewport* (the eye icon) aren't consistent. Is there a way to always show all of the parameters? I'd like all of them to be visible always.

Attached is the same scene, switching from *Layout* to *Shading* tabs.

[image: layout to shading view]

Comment: In an empty project arrange the elements within each Layout the way you want them. Then save the file as your default project. Next time you open blender the layout should be consistent. To load old projects into the new layouts, disable the "Load UI" box on the open project window (or in the system preferences)

Comment: You can modify these icons and more by clicking the sieve icon in the topright corner of the outliner

Comment: @susu can you post that as answer so I can accept it?